# Get all associated objects on self join objects and its children

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I am trying to find all the associated friends with my Person, self-join, record and all its children.

Here is an example I am trying to run. I have a Person record, lets call it `@person`, that has 4 'children'.

These children all have many friends.

When I query `@person`, I want all the friends of itself and then the four children below it.

Is there a way to do this without going: `friends = @parent.friends + @parent.children.map {|c| c.friends }`?

Would really love to do it with one database query. My database is postgresql also.

Here is an example of how my records are set up.

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => "Person", :foreign_key => "parent_person_id"
  has_many :children, :class_name => "Person", :foreign_key => "parent_person_id"
  has_many :friends

end

class Friend < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
end
```

Comment: for children the foregin key should be the `id` and not the `parent_person_id`

Comment: @arivarasan - It works how it is currently set up. I am definitely able to find children and the parent of the records. The fields on my record are: `id: integer, parent_genre_id: integer, title: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As for *Children*, your *foreign_key* must be **id**.

```
has_many :children, :class_name => "Person", :foreign_key => "id"
```

Try this:

```
people_ids = @parent.children.map(&:id).push(@parent.id)
Friend.where(person_id: people_ids)
```

Or you can eager load the associated table something like:

```
friends = Person.includes(:friends).where("parent_person_id = ? or id = ?", [@parent.id, @parent.id]).map(&friends)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know I can grab all the id of the children doing something similar to your answer. I could do it with two database queries and not pull all the records into ruby using `.pluck(:id)'. Any idea how to combine your two database queries into a single one?

Comment: Well, try eager loading, something like Person.includes(:friends).where(id: people_ids), I don't think you can eliminate calling children query tho.

Comment: Why don't you consider using NoSQL DB like MongoDB, you will be able to embed data to your Person table and it will take constant time to query the results?

Comment: Please try this and let me know if it works for you. **Person.includes(:friends).where("parent_id = ? or id = ?", [@parent.id, @parent.id] ).friends**

Comment: I fixed a small bugs in yours with the arguments for the where statement. I was able to get the person and all their children but not their friends if the `.friends` was on the end. `Person.includes(:friends).where("parent_id = ? or id = ?", @parent.id, @parent.id).friends`

Comment: You can easily iterate thought the result by *.each{|person| person.friends}* and check out the log, it should be one query for all ;)

Comment: I beat my head against the wall with a rails4.2 model.  I didn't want `id`, I wanted `parent_person_id` on both the child and the parent relationships.  That was the only way that it worked.

Answer (score 1):

**Ancestry**

Why don't you look at the [`ancestry` gem](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry)?

This basically allows you to define `children` in your models without having to define associations (thus preventing an unnecessary query). You'll be able to do it like this:

```
#app/models/person.rb
Class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_ancestry
end
```

The gem creates an `ancestry` column in your table, which you can populate with "child" objects:

[image]

This allows you to select the `children` of your model like this:

```
@person = Person.find params[:id]
@person.children.each do |child|
     child.name
end
```

Here are the various methods `has_ancestry` appends to your `model`:

[image]

--

**Caveat**

A caveat to this is if you want multi-nested items, you'll need to use set the entire tree of parents like in our example above:

```
parent_id_1/parent_id_2
```

Comment: Yeah I took a look at that guy. It was overkill for what I needed at the moment. Really only have a parent and a child level of people as of now. Will definitely keep it in mind though!